# Writing info from an array and cookies to a text file with PHP

Tags: php, file, text, fwrite

I'm trying to write info from an array and from cookies (that have been put into variables, i.e. $usergatsby) into a text file that has been created with PHP. Below is the code of what I would like to be written in the text file. I've tried writing it in with fwrite() and file_put_contents, but I always get a server error. I was wondering if anyone knew how I would go about doing this?

```
$emailmsg = "Order: " . foreach ($productarray as $book=>$info)
                    {if ($book > 0)
                    {echo $info . ", Quantity: " . $book . "<br><br>";}
        } . "// Price: " . $usergatsby*12.99 + $usercatcher*10.99 + $userwaves*8.99 + $userstranger*7.99 + $userulysses*18.99 + $userpride*6.99 + $usermockingbird*9.99 + $userroad*11.99;


$textFile = text.txt;
$fileHandle = fopen($textFile, 'w') or die('There was an error.');

fwrite($fileHandle, $emailmsg);
fclose($fileHandle);
```

Comment: What's the server error message?

Comment: before you use fwrite you need use fopen you know? Show us the code where you'r trying to write some file. Maybe it's the permission on folder or maybe you'r passing the wrong parameter on fopen method.

Comment: I updated the code to show the whole write process.

Comment: The error is HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error), which is the same error that I see anytime I have a syntax error. There's no error if I just try to write a normal string, which is why I didn't originally post all the code. The problem just seems to be with me trying to write more than ordinary string data.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding quotes to the filename `$textFile = 'text.txt';` because i tried it and it spelled out an error without them, also you double check the CHMOD to make sure you have the right permission.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I know the file permissions aren't the issue. I'm starting to think it's a syntactical issue with $emailmsg, because I've tried it with a regular string and it works fine. But I can't figure out what the syntactical issue would be?

Comment: I modified the $emailmsg included a math operator and a date function and it still working fine, Did you try to echo the $emailmsg and read it carefully?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at it piece by piece and there's something wrong with the concatenation of the array.